# Why can't I find my settings.xml under ~/.m2?

Tags: maven-3, macos-sierra

Why can't I find my **settings.xml** under `~/.m2`?

Note: I'm currently running Apache Maven `3.3.9` on my machine.

[image]

Comment: simply because you don't have put some into that location...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> The Maven install: ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml
>
> The user’s install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
>
> The former settings.xml are also called global settings, the latter
>   settings.xml are referred to as user settings. If both files exists,
>   their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being
>   dominant.
>
> Tip: If you need to create user-specific settings from scratch, it’s
>   easiest to copy the global settings from your Maven installation to
>   your ${user.home}/.m2 directory. Maven’s default settings.xml is a
>   template with comments and examples so you can quickly tweak it to
>   match your needs.

[Maven Settings Reference Guide](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

So simply

1. navigate to your maven directory under `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`
2. and copy&paste your settings.xml to `${user.home}/.m2/`

Answer (score 7):

There is no settings.xml file by default.

If you need it you should create the file.

Answer (score 7):

Run `mvn -X` to get information about your maven installation like below

Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-47-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1

In the above information you will be able to find settings.xml location like below

```
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/test/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/share/maven/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /home/test/.m2/toolchains.xml
```