# how to troubleshoot maven dependency error

Tags: java, maven

I have this error:

> Offline / Missing artifact javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3

I am relatively new to maven How to debug this error ?

This is the code I used, the error comes from `artifacrId`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensourcebim</groupId>
            <artifactId>bimserver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.158-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The requested version is not available in the [repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensourcebim/bimserver). You can use the following one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensourcebim</groupId>
    <artifactId>bimserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.152</version>
</dependency>
```

Please pay attention that using the `SNAPSHOT` versions are not the right decision, in order to get more information about SNAPSHOT check this relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I triyed it and made `maven updated project `, it did not work. I have to work with SNAPSHOT because it a cloned git repo from bimserver

Comment: @celia I see. So maybe this question can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715321/how-to-download-snapshot-version-from-maven-snapshot-repository

Comment: it might be that I did not enable snapshots or maven not correctly configured, No idea how to check that.

Comment: @celia I guess you need to apply the accepted answer of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7717234/3881354 and If you cannot find `settings.xml` in the `~/.m2/` directory, create a new one and edit it. By default there is no `settings.xml` unless you want to change the default settings. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40255910/3881354